# WooCommerce Login & Registration on separate pages incorrect password

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using the following solution to have separate login and registration pages for WooCommerce.

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/woocommerce-login-registration-on-separate-pages

It works great, however if a user enters the wrong credentials there is no error displayed.  It just reloads the login page.  I've tried adding code to my functions.php to handle the login errors, however the errors are not displayed.  I believe it is because I have the custom login and registration pages.

How can I add error messages to the custom login pages when a user enters the wrong password?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`wc_print_notices()`](http://hookr.io/functions/wc_print_notices/) function to display messages and errors which are stored in the session

Add this function In the top of your custom login and registration page

```
wc_print_notices();
//your login and registration form code
```